# Why is my JQuery script not replacing the data attribute with the right iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three videos which have a placeholder image. When a user clicks the image placeholder, the inner HTML is replaced with the iframe and the video plays.

At first, it seems to work fine when you click the first video on the left. However, if you click a different placeholder image, (last video) the video duplicate across all three list items.

Any help solve this is appreciated.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Al-76/pen/MWKQRbP

```
<ul class="video-examples-list">
    <li>
          <p>Dog running<p>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="responsive-iframe">
                <div class="video">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x450" class="swap" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/k-EPxNDCaeY?autoplay=1">
                  <div class="play"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
          <p>Frogs Jumping<p>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="responsive-iframe">
                <div class="video">
                   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x450" class="swap" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KCtSxQDN37w?autoplay=1">
                  <div class="play"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
          <p>Lambs Jumping<p>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="responsive-iframe">
                <div class="video">
                   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x450" class="swap" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OwxIzr7CbcQ?autoplay=1">
                  <div class="play"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My JQuery code is as below;

```
 $('.play').on('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      video = '<iframe frameborder="0" src="' + $('img.swap').attr('data-video') + '" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
      $(this).parent('.video').replaceWith(video);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `$('img.swap').attr('data-video')` will take the desired attr of the *first* image with class `swap`. To make your code find the sibling `img.swap` instead, you can use jQuery's `siblings()`:

```
video = '<iframe frameborder="0" src="' + $(this).siblings('img.swap').attr('data-video') + '" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

Where `this` points to the clicked div with class `play`.

**Side note:** When you click the three divs sequentially from left to right, the reason it *seems* to work is because after you click the first div, you are replacing the parent node with the iframe, removing the first `img.swap`. Therefore, on the next call to the event handler, there are only two `img.swap` left: the second and the third, and so `$('img.swap').attr('data-video')` will now refer to the second video.

Answer (score 1):

`$('img.swap').attr('data-video')` will always get the value of the first element found in the collection

You need to target the instance in same container as the button by using traverse methods. There are various ways you can traverse there

Try changing to

```
$(this).siblings('img.swap').attr('data-video')
// OR
$(this).prev().attr('data-video')
// OR 
$(this).closest('.video').find('img.swap').attr('data-video')
// OR 
$(this).parent().find('img.swap').attr('data-video')
```